# ORACLE SQL adjust date for timezone without casting to timestamp or char

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper, timezone-offset

For ORACLE SQL, Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production,

Is there a way to convert a date (including date/time) from GMT to local time (allowing for Daylight Savings adjustment) directly just as a date (including date/time)?

I have seen several solutions that involve timestamps or that use timestamps and character conversions with the relevant timezone offset.

However, I'd like to keep everything as a date.

Example using timestamp conversion:

```
SELECT OUR_DATE, from_tz(cast( OUR_DATE as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern'
from OUR_DB.OUR_TBL;
```

Comment: Not sure what the "example" is supposed to illustrate. It has several syntax errors (fatal ones - Oracle will just throw one error after another as you are fixing them), so perhaps it's not the best example possible. Aside from that: Since Oracle only has the "time zone" concept for timestamps, not for dates, you can't do it directly. But what's wrong with converting the date to a timestamp with time zone, converting to the time zone you need, and then **converting back to date** (including time-of-day) if that's what you need in the end?

Comment: Yes, I found that out.  I put in a better example.

Comment: Also, do you need to convert to "**local**" time zone (meaning, if two different users are in different time zones, they get ***different*** results), or do you need to convert to a fixed, hard-coded time zone like `US/Central`? Oracle can do both - and they are not the same thing!

Comment: I want a fixed time zone.  Also, does the fixed time zone include an automatic Daylight Savings Time (DST) adjustment?

Comment: The DST adjustment depends on the time zone and how you present it. You can give a time zone like -05:00 - that is a fixed offset from GMT (no DST adjustment). Time zone regions, like you are using (`US/Eastern`) do have automatic DST adjustment - but you must make sure the database is up-to-date re: possible changes in local DST regulations, which do change over time.

Comment: Term `GMT` is a bit old style. Nowadays you use `UTC`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - That is true, but it's just a matter of practice in the industry; theoretically, GMT is right and UTC is wrong. GMT is a time zone; UTC is not, it is a standard on which time zones (including GMT) are based. A timestamp, technically speaking, can't be in the "UTC time zone" - there is no such thing. You are right, though, that the common **usage** is UTC - wrong as it may be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need something like this (which would be a lot easier if Oracle also had "date with time stamp" data types):

```
...
cast(from_tz(cast(your_date as timestamp), 'UTC') at time zone 'US/Eastern'
  as date) as your_column_alias
...
```

Cast the date as timestamp, so you can give it a time zone (`UTC` is the new `GMT` - that's a separate issue), convert to your required time zone, and then convert back to date - no time zone, no fractional seconds.

Comment: Very nice.  A question:  Is DST automatically implied by 'US/Central'?

Comment: Observation:  In my system, an Oracle 'date' *IS* actually a date/time with non-trivial time and it has the fractional seconds, which aren't problematic for me here, though they can be irritating on some reports.

Comment: @JosephDoggie - `US/Central` does, indeed, have DST in it. Regarding your observation: In all Oracle systems, the "date" data type includes time-of-day; it may be 00:00:00 (midnight), but it's always present. But the other thing... no, your Oracle database, in the `date` data type, does NOT have fractional seconds. If it does then it's not Oracle. That is **exactly** the distinction between "date" and "timestamp" (with no time zone component). Perhaps we aren't talking about the same thing; "fractional seconds" means the thing at the end of 03:14:25.339021

Comment: All the fractional seconds seem to be .000 so that may just be an artifact of the database-tool I am using (in this case, dbeaver), but thanks!